# MS-Access SQL : Join expression not supported

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 tables A and B. I want to create a third one, C. C must contain each record that is in A but not in B, and each record that is in A and B.

I've tried the following :

`SELECT A.* INTO C FROM (A INNER JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id) LEFT JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id WHERE B.Id IS NULL;`

But it gives me the error message : `JOIN expression not supported.`

When there's only the `INNER JOIN` or the `LEFT JOIN`, it works perfectly. But for some reason when I combine both with the brackets, it doesn't work.

I believe I am using MS-Access 2013, if that helps.
By the way, I'm an Access and an SQL newbie.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Access-SQL-d5f21d10-cd73-4507-925e-bb26e377fe7e), you cannot nest joins in outer join operands. However (as in standard SQL but not documented) you can use `T A INNER JOIN U B` [as with `,`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-FROM-clause-2a7d031c-6912-4e8c-a644-590940ddaed1) in `FROM` where T is a base name or subselect. `,` calculates `CROSS JOIN` ie `INNER JOIN ON 1=1` but binds looser than `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct logic is:

```
SELECT A.* INTO C
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE B.Id IS NULL;
```

You do not need two joins.  My guess is that the problem with your query is that `B` appears twice in the `FROM` clause, without a table alias.  MS Access doesn't know what the second `B` refers to.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ! I tried your query, it works, C contains the records which are only in A, but not the records that are in A and B for some reason.

Comment: Alright I just had to remove the `WHERE`, it works perfectly, thanks a lot !